# Is there any way to ensure that a node is only connected to one instance of a particular relationship type

Tags: neo4j, cypher

To clarify, let's assume that we have nodes representing people and the following relationships: "BIOLOGICAL_MOTHER" and "BIOLOGICAL_FATHER".

Then, for any person node, said node can only have one "BIOLOGICAL_MOTHER" and one "BIOLOGICAL_FATHER".  How can we ensure that this is the case?

Answer (score 2):

No.   [Neo4J currently only supports uniqueness constraints](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-schema-constraints.html).

I believe several people are working on different schema constructs for neo4j, that would permit you to constrain graphs in any number of different ways.  What it seems you're asking for boils down to a database constraint that if there is a relationship of type BIOLOGICAL_FATHER from one person to another, that the DB may not accept any creation of new relationships of that same type.   In other words, relationship cardinality constraints, by relationship type.

At the moment, I think the best you can do is verify in your application code that such a relationship doesn't exist before creating it, but the DB won't do this checking for you.

The particular constraint you're looking for sounds easy enough, hopefully a neo4j dev will jump in here and say, "Oh, no worries, that's planned for release XYZ" - but I'm not sure about that.

More broadly, there are a number of issues with graphs that make constraints very tricky.  In my personal graph domain, I'd like to make it impossible to create new relationships such that they would introduce cycles in the graph over a particular relationship type.  (E.g. (a)-[:owns]->(b)-[:owns]->(a) is extremely undesirable for me).   This would be a very costly constraint to actually enforce in the general case, since verifying whether a new relationship was OK could potentially involve traversing a huge graph.

Over the long run, it seems reasonable that neo4j might implement *local* constraints, but still shy away from anything that implied *non-local* constraint checking.

Answer (score 2):

Steve,

In terms of Cypher, if I am given two names of people - say Sam and Dave, and wish to make Sam the father of Dave, but only if Dave doesn't yet have a father, I could do something like this:

```
MATCH (f {name : 'Sam'}), (s {name : 'Dave'})
WHERE NOT (s)<-[:FATHER]-()
CREATE (f)-[:FATHER]->(s)
```

If Dave already has a father the WHERE clause filters Dave out, which means no relationship will be created.

Grace and peace,

Jim